# c to assembler: char buff[256] converts to sub $0x108,%esp

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to understand some dissembled code and the math therein. By my calculations 256 dec = 0x100 hex. When I dissemble a `char buff[256]`, I see it allocated by `sub $0x108,%esp`

Here is the c code

```
void vuln(char* arg) {
    char buf[256];
    strcpy(buf, arg);
}
```

Here is the dissembled instructions

```
push   %ebp
mov    %esp, %ebp
sub    $0x108,%esp
sub    $0x8,%esp
pushl  0x8(%ebp)
lea    -0x108(%ebp),%eax
push   %eax
call   8048300 <strcpy@plt>
add    $0x10,%esp
leave
ret
```

I also do not understand the `add $0x10,%esp` at the end. I assume that we are removing the return value from strcpy, but why `$0x10`? strcpy returns a `char *`, shouldn't that be `$0x8`?

Comment: You forgot to compile with optimization enabled. Otherwise the compiler will generate garbage code. Note that you still might see more memory being allocated, which is for usually for alignment reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in this [Agner Fog document on calling conventions](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf), Chapter 5:

> The Gnu compiler version 3.x and later for 32-bit Linux and Mac OS X makes the stack
>   pointer aligned by 16 at every function call instruction.

So, as @Anty explained in their answer, the default value of the `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` is 4, to get an alignment of 2<sup>4</sup>.

When checking the alignment of the stack is useful to adopt a convention that explicitly show how much the stack pointer **is not** aligned.
I invented my own, that takes the form *@m+n* (e.g. @16+4) and means that the stack pointer is at and address *n* bytes **less** than a multiple of *m* (e.g. 4 bytes less that a multiple of 16, like 0x000c, 0x001c, 0x002c and so on).
This is useful because the stack grows downward, so if the stack pointer is at, say, @16+4 then after a `push ebp` it is at @16+8 and so on (accounting for the modular nature of the alignment).

Before `vuln` is called the stack is at *@16+0* (as enforced by the compiler).
Just after being called, due to the implicit push of the return address, it is as *@16+4*.

The prolog is:

```
;Every annotation shows the alignment of the stack 
; AFTER the annotated instruction has executed

push   %ebp            ;@16+8
mov    %esp, %ebp
```

Now the compiler has to allocate 0x100 bytes, but it wants them to be allocated on the preferred alignment, just doing a `sub $0x108,%esp` would result in a stack pointer at *@16+8+0x100* = *@16+0x108* === *@16+8*.
To make it to the next 16 byte boundary, eight more bytes are needed, thus the 0x108 size.

```
sub    $0x108,%esp       ;@16+0, Aligned
```

Next it needs to perform a call, at the call instruction the stack needs to be aligned again.
So far it is, but after pushing the parameters it won't be anymore.
Since `strcpy` has two 32-bit parameters, eight bytes in total, the compiler moves the stack pointer eight more bytes down (8+8=16) to respect the alignment constrain

```
sub    $0x8,%esp               ;@16+8

pushl  0x8(%ebp)               ;@16+12
lea    -0x108(%ebp),%eax
push   %eax                    ;@16+0, Aligned
call   8048300 <strcpy@plt>
```

Now, the [C calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) mandates that it is the caller that cleans up the stack.
Two parameters were pushed, so and `add $0x8,%esp` is needed.
Plus another `add $0x8,%esp` to balance the `sub $0x8,%esp` above.
These two are combined into a single instruction.

```
add    $0x10,%esp              ;@16+0, Aligned
```

Note that this has nothing to do with the return value and type of the function.
It is the arguments pushed that count.

Finally the prolog

```
leave                          ;@16+8
ret                            ;@16+4
```

Comment: Thank you @Margaret Bloom, I suspected that it had to with stack alignment, but didn't fully understand until you broke it down step by step. This is great!

Answer (score 3):

What you see is the effect of stack alignment - particularly `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` compiler option. In your case

```
-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4
```

which means align to 2^4=16

so the code compiles to

```
vuln(char*):
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 264
        sub     esp, 8
        push    DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
        lea     eax, [ebp-264]
        push    eax
        call    strcpy
        add     esp, 16
        nop
        leave
        ret
```

If you change it to

```
-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2
```

it will align to 4 bytes (2^2) and code you will get is

```
vuln(char*):
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 256
        push    DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
        lea     eax, [ebp-256]
        push    eax
        call    strcpy
        add     esp, 8
        nop
        leave
        ret
```

As you can see in first case it is `sub esp, 8` and `add esp, 16` (to consume extra 8 bytes) whereas in second case just `add esp, 8`